# PHP syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING

Tags: php, laravel

Pls help. On reset password page I am getting error as

```
syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING
```

My code

```
To reset your password, complete this form: <?php echo URL::to(\'user/reset\', array({$token})); ?>.
```

or same code in laravel if this helps:

```
To reset your password, complete this form: {{ URL::to(\'user/reset\', array($token)) }}.
```

Comment: Why are you using `\'` rather than `'` to enclose strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
{{ URL::to('user/reset', array($token)) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not escape (`\`) the `'` characters.

```
To reset your password, complete this form:
{{ URL::to('user/reset', array($token)) }}.
```

Read the PHP manual: [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)